# Android's drmserver/libdrmframework_jni.so

Tags: android, build, drm

I found drmserver & libdrmframework_jni.so are not existing in /system/
bin/ and /system/lib/.

How to build the libdrmframework_jni.so into system.img by android's make
command automatically?

When I use mmm ./framework/base/drm/drmserver and mmm ./framework/base/
drm/jni, they can install correctly into system related folder.

Thanks!

Gary